# Getting a MalformedURLException on an encoded URL

Tags: java, url, character-encoding, urlencode

I have functionality which will take in URLs and process them. These URLs can contain characters such as `[` or spaces.  The way to deal with this is to encode the URL.

But this comes to the second problem, such as dealing with forward slashes. Apache URL does not allow `%2F` the encoded value for `/`.

I have a workaround string replace `%2F` with `/` after the encoding. But this feels a tad hacky.
I have looked at the different types of encoders, including URL encoders, but I cant find anything that will allow me to encode a whole URL string, that wont throw a `MalformedURLException`.

Comment: I voted to close this question because there is no example code. Please [edit] your post to include a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  At the very least, what are some examples of URLs that need to be encoded and some examples of URLs that give the exception when encoded.

Answer (score 0):

```java
String encodedURL = UriUtils.encodePath(request.getUrl(), "UTF-8");
```

Works no extra functionality needed.

Comment: What package is `UriUtils` from?

Comment: This doesn't looks like a correct solution to me.   If you encode the path portion of `http://example.com/foo/bar` you would end up with `http://example.com/foo%2Fbar` which is not the same URL.